# does svn has something similar to p4 jobs?

Tags: svn, command, equivalent

I want to associate svn commit id's with a bug id and report it to bug/issue tracking system. Does `svn` have jobs similar to p4 jobs (see http://perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_jobs.html). A p4 job is a unique string containing one or more p4 changelists or commit ids. This p4 job string can be associated with any bug tracking system. Is it possible to do that with `svn`?

Comment: You may get a better response with a brief explanation of what p4 jobs *are*, or at least a link.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_jobs.html . A p4 job is a unique string containing one or more p4 changelists or commit ids. This p4 job string can be associated with any bug tracking system. So do we have anything similar in svn.

Comment: Included the comment in the question. Please use the `edit` label in the future.